# Browser not seting cookie to client domain but server domain only

Tags: cookies, fastify

I have 2 projects, `app` client and `api` server.
When i request from server cookie i receive it under `set-cookie` but for some reason browser does not set it under its `app` domain but continue setting it under `api` domain.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also noticed that when i need to send cookie the browser knows to take it from `api` domain, but how does that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share cookies between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookies-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Comment: No sure if the path should include https?